# Abstract property with type declared in derived class?

Tags: c#, abstract-class

Is it possible to have an abstract property which returns a type defined in the derived class:

```
abstract class baseClass
{
    public abstract e_Type type { get; }
}

class derived : baseClass
{
    public enum e_Type
    {
        type1,
        type2
    }

    private e_Type _type;
    public e_Type type { get { return _type; } }
}
```

or must I return an int and map it in the derived class. Any other suggestions welcome.

Comment: never forget to add override keyword, otherwise public e_Type type { get { return _type; } } is declaration of new property, hiding base property.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure you can:

```
abstract class BaseClass<T>
{
    public abstract T Type { get; }
}

class Derived : BaseClass<EType>
{    
    public enum EType
    {
        type1,
        type2
    }

    private EType _type;
    public override EType Type { get { return _type; } }
}
```

You don't even need to declare it as abstract:

```
class BaseClass<T> {
    private T _type;
    public T Type { get { return _type; } }
}
```

which you can then use as:

```
BaseClass<EType> classInst = new BaseClass<EType>();
```

Comment: Your concrete `BaseClass` isn't valid, because it doesn't implement the property.

Answer (score 5):

Well, you can specify the type explicitly - but it has to be *a* type, not just "one called e_Type declared within the concrete subclass".

Or you could make it a generic type, of course, like this:

```
public abstract class BaseClass<T>
{
    public abstract T Type { get; }
}

public class Derived : BaseClass<EType>
{
    public enum EType
    {
        ...
    }

    private EType type;
    public EType Type { get { return type; } }
}
```

Without knowing what you're trying to achieve, it's hard to suggest an appropriate design.